# Cloud Firestore Swift: How to display number field in label

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a number field from Cloud Firestore that needs to be displayed as a string within a label.

Usually, if the field were a string, I can just execute this code

```
db.collection("users").document(uid ?? "UID not yet loaded in viewDidLoad()")
    .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "Couldn't update text field TextUser according to database")
        } else {
            if let dbUsername = snapshot?["username"] as? String {
                self.textUser?.text = dbUsername
            }
```

That works because "username" in the document is of a value string.
But this won't work because "cash" in the document is of a value number.

```
if let dbCash = snapshot? ["cash"] as? String {
    self.labeCash?.text = dbCash
}
```

I might just have to convert the number, whatever type they use, into a string. But how would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
if let dbCash = snapshot? ["cash"] as? NSNumber {
   self.labeCash?.text = dbCash.stringValue
}
```

Comment: That prints "2", which is the current value in Firestore. How would I put that in a label?